# How to INSERT INTO an array column of postgres using postman JSON?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, postman

I have a table with an array column `myarray text[]`. 
I have created an endpoint for inserting into array

```
exports.createVaraus = async (id, myarray) =>$    try {
        const result = await client.query('INSERT INTO mytable (id, myarray) VALUES ($1, $2) RETURNING id', 
 [id, myarray]
        );
        return result.rows[0]
    } catch (err) {
        throw new Error(err);
    }
}
```

Now when I do POST with postman with following JSON:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "myarray": {"column1": "test"}
}
```

I get the following error:

> "message": "error: malformed array literal:
>   \"{\"column1\":\"test\"}\""

What is wrong and how to do this properly?

Comment: First `{"column1": "test"}` really is not an array, it's an object, the array looks like `["val1", "val2"]`, second: what is the type of your column in database? Also, I'll suggest using `json` field, cause it's much easier to work with it from backend (js, java etc).

Comment: Fixed the array post to ["val1", "val2"].When usin PUT i get error:  "message": "error: invalid input syntax for type integer: \"{\"myarray\":[\"8-10\"]}\""

Comment: How is `mytable` defined in SQL? And what nodejs framework are you using, how is the request body getting passed to your `createVaraus` function?

Comment: Answered with details you requested. Tough I dont really understand the error as the type of that column is not integet but text.

Comment: Perhaps my JSON syntax is wrong. Anyone know how to put into a JSON array correctly?

Answer (score 0):

My table holds 2 columns: id and myarray.

I am using express.

My request body:

```
  exports.updateVaraus = async(request, response) => {
    try {
      let {id} = request.params;
      const varausObject = request.body;
      const updatedVaraus = await varausModel.updateVaraus(varausObject, id);
      response.status(200).send(updatedVaraus);
    } catch (err) {
      response.status(400).send({message: err.message});
    }
  }
```